# Keras, how to keep learning on live data?

Tags: database, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, quantitative-finance

I am developing the model using for stock market prediction. And got a question, the life data is coming every second, and the future price depends on its data. 
My question is:

1) for example, I made prediction, and then second data comes and I need to do one more prediction but cosider the first data as well and so on.

Could you lead me how to process that correctly.

Comment: Look into recurrent neural networks with LSTM units. Seems a perfect fit for your use case. Essentially, the previous outputs are *remembered* and used to influence the output of the current inputs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds great for me, but how will prediction code looks like. for example x1= incoming data1, x2=incoming data2...  model.predict(x1) and then model.predict(x2). Or i should use model.predict(x1) and then model.predict(x1,x2)?????

Comment: There are many variables which govern your question of "but how will prediction code look like".. Please read https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I appritiate your time and advices. I research the reading you gave and if I have question I will ask )) thank you again!

Comment: I will be honest with you, Sam, but your link did not give me an answer. Is there is a chance to make it clear with another words? :) at least could u give me the keras function name to use the live data training. I read a lot and somebody advice use model.save and then model.load and fit and save again. But I think thats wrong way. Some body advice use fit_generator(). But I am also concert about that. Could you please give me your thoughts about that, I would appriciate so much.

Comment: With all due respect, blind-re-use of ideas from Noam Chomsky / implemented besides many other approaches by just the LSTM-tools in computational linguistics and trying to re-inject this concept into Quant-Finance to successfully predict on live stream of Market-Data, is not a "**fair advice**", is it?

Comment: Mr user3666197, is there is a chance that you can advice to me? How continue teaching model in a fastest way?

Comment: OK fair enough.. I was aiming more toward an introduction to the model structure in general not pointing to a tutorial which achieves exactly what OP is after. If you have good material on the subject matter then please do share. @MaksKozyrev here is a Kaggle tutorial I've turned up on a quick search: https://www.kaggle.com/pablocastilla/predict-stock-prices-with-lstm Maybe this can help you.